# Make mathematica treat $e_i^2$ as numeric

Tags: numerics, pattern-matching, core-language

With `NumericQ[symbol] = True`, I can declare that a symbol is numeric. I want the expressions matching: $$e_{\text{i$\_$}?\text{IntegerQ}}^2$$ to be treated as numerical expressions too.

```
e /: NumericQ[Subscript[e, i_?IntegerQ]^2] = True;
```

doesn't work. Also, I can't use `NumericFunction` because it's too restrictive. Is there something like `NumericPattern`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is another way: you can fool the depth-1 tag rule for `UpValues` with a few temporary symbols. Here is an example:

```
ClearAll[e];
e /: Subscript[e, i_?IntegerQ] := e /: Subscript[e, i] =
  Module[{el},
    el /: el^p_ := el /: el^p =
       Module[{elp},
          elp /: NumericQ[elp] = True;
          Format[elp] := TraditionalForm[Subscript["e", i]^p];
          elp
       ];
    el /: NumericQ[el] = True;
    Format[el] := TraditionalForm[Subscript["e", i]];
    el]
```

What this does is to substitute `Subscript[e, i_?IntegerQ]` by some symbol, which will print just as the original one, but will have some rules attached which will do what you need. Now,

```
NumericQ[Subscript[e,1]]
(* True *)

NumericQ[Subscript[e,1]^2]

(* True *)
```

The advantage of this method is that it is flexible. You are not tied to just powers of your subscript, it can be easily generalized to other functions.

Answer (score 16):

Everything depends on what you try to do with this. First you could use `Subsuperscript` and get rid of one level which is introduced by your `Power`

```
Subscript[e,3]^2//FullForm
(* Power[Subscript[e,3],2] *)

Subsuperscript[e,3,2]//FullForm
(* Subsuperscript[e,3,2] *)
```

Both forms look equally in the front-end, but now you can use `TagSet` to transform all `e` with integer-subscript to a different form which *displays* as it would still be the normal `e`:

```
e/:Subsuperscript[e,i_?IntegerQ,2]:=eNumeric[i,2];
e/:Subsuperscript[e,i_,2]:=eNonNumeric[i,2];
SetAttributes[eNumeric,{NumericFunction}];
(Format[#[i_,2]]:=TraditionalForm[Subsuperscript["e",i,2]])&/@{eNumeric,eNonNumeric};
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Notation` package to treat anything like function and then set whatever attributes to this function:

[image]

The only problem is that `Notation` don't support test patterns, so to make an expression numeric with only integer indexes:

[image]

Comment: Please try to include the code in textual form for two reasons: 1) Other users may want to copy/paste it and 2) Your answer will be better indexed for web searches. Thnx!

Comment: @belisarius I didn't make it textual because those boxes inside `Notation` are very messy and unreadable.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm not suggesting to replace the images. Anyway, your choice :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make `e` [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ) and also give [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript) the [`NumericFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericFunction) attribute:

```
NumericQ[e] = True;
SetAttributes[Subscript, NumericFunction]
```

Then:

```
NumericQ /@ {Subscript[e, 2]^2, Sin[Subscript[e, 1]^3 + Subscript[e, 2]], Log[Subscript[e, 1]]
```

> {True, True, True}