# The shortcut for Subsuperscript doesn't work?

Tags: bugs, formatting, keyboard

[The document for Subsuperscript](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Subsuperscript.html?q=Subsuperscript&lang=en) says that:

> To enter a subsuperscript in a notebook, use either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> to begin a
>   regular subscript or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> to begin a regular superscript. After
>   typing the first script, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> to move to the opposite script
>   position. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> moves out of the subscript or superscript
>   position.

This just create a expresion that **looks like** a symbol with subsuperscript! Specifically, I typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> and a regular subscript / superscript appeared, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> and the opposite script appeared, and after I moved the cursor out of the symbol by pressing <kbd>→</kbd> and checked its `InputForm`, what I saw is **not** something like

```
Subsuperscript[a, x, y]
```

but

```
Subscript[a, x]^y
```

*Snapshot:*

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What's wrong with it, I misunderstood the document? I use *Mathematica 8.0.4* and *Windows Vista Home Basic 32bit*.

Comment: works as expected with 8.0.4 on OS X 10.6.8

Comment: The standard procedure (i.e. Ctrl+^ then Ctrl+%) works for me at Win. XP or Win. 7/Math. 8 or 9. May it be the Vista peculiarity?

Comment: @Szabolcs My keyboard is the same as yours i.e. I actually type `Ctrl`+`6` and then `Ctrl`+`5`. Let me add it to the question.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch A friend of mine reproduced the error with 8.0.4 on Windows 7 64bit…

Comment: This error also appears in version 7 on Windows Vista 32bit. The `StandardForm` for `Subscript[a, x]^y` looks just like that for `Subsuperscript[a, x, y]`, have you checked its `InputForm` or tried to `Set` a value to it?

Comment: I noticed this behaviour when writing up [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16981/187) answer, but since I was on Linux then, I thought it's not worth mentioning. I can now confirm this on OSX 10.8 with M9 and M8.0.4. @Szabolcs Are you sure your combination creates a `Subsuperscript`? It doesn't here!

Comment: @halirutan I'm sorry, you're right. I can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that when you use <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>%</kbd> to create something that looks like $x_a^b$, the underlying box representation will be a `SubsuperscriptBox`.  However, the interpretation of a `SubsuperscriptBox["x", "a", "b"]` box is the expression `Subscript[x, a]^b`.  The expression `Subsuperscript[x, a, b]`is formatted as `TemplateBox[{"x","a","b"},
  "Subsuperscript"]]` in StandardForm.

As you noticed, as of version 9, the documentation doesn't match the actual behaviour.

Can you contact WRI about this so they can sort it out (either on the documentation side or the software side)?

Comment: Well, OK, let me try to contact them.

Comment: The reply from WRI: "Hello,
Thank you for taking the time to let us know about this issue in the documentation. I have forwarded this report to our developers in charge of this are of the documentation so that it can be fixed in a future release of Mathematica.

Sincerely,
Technical Support
Wolfram Research, Inc."

Comment: Documentation will be fixed in a future release (probably not in the v9.0.x cycle).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have [`SubsuperscriptBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsuperscriptBox.html) parse as [`Subsuperscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsuperscript.html) instead of `Power[Subscript[..], ..]`, you could do the following:

```
Unprotect[SubsuperscriptBox];
SubsuperscriptBox /: MakeExpression[SubsuperscriptBox[x_,y_,z_], f:StandardForm] :=
Thread[
    Subsuperscript[
        MakeExpression[x, f],
        MakeExpression[y, f],
        MakeExpression[z, f]
    ],
    HoldComplete
]
Protect[SubsuperscriptBox];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Mathematica's Notation package to define what your particular form means. Here I create a datatype G[] from sub- and superscripted letter e. Note in the final example that regular superscripting still means raise to a power.

[image: Here's the code:]