# How to input superscript without using Superscript[x,y]?

Tags: keyboard, input-alias

Just as the title, how can I input superscript without using `Superscript[x,y]`? To be more specific, I'm not trying to type `Power` in 2D form, I just need `Superscript` i.e.

> FullForm@$x^y$
>
> ```
> Superscript[x, y]
> ```

Comment: [Typing Superscripts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TypingSuperscripts.html)

Comment: You need `Superscript` or `Power` that looks like `Superscript`? If the former, you'd better emphasize this in your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I need Superscript just as Subscript, i.e, FullForm[$x^y$]= Superscript[x,y].

Comment: You need to add something like @Karsten7. in your post or the commenters won't receive a reminder. As mentioned in the former comment, you'd better clarify this point in your question, this time I've done it for you.

Comment: Then what exactly do you want? A short cut for `Superscript` like `Ctrl+_` for `Subscript`? A button that'll create a template for `Superscript`? Or anything other than typing `Superscript` directly? (@JasonB I think I should remind you. )

Comment: @xzczd - remind me?  I'm very confused by what is wanted here.  Ctrl+6 does what is needed, literally inputting a superscript without typing `Superscript`.  There is a button in the upper left corner of the [Basic Math Input](http://i.imgur.com/0KElN5M.png) palette as well

Comment: @JasonB The question is indeed confusing at the beginning, but now OP has clarified it in the comment: he/she needs `Superscript` rather than `Power`. They're totally different, though looks the same in the front end. BTW you may also feel [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17867/1871) interesting.

Comment: This question should be marked as a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33672/1871

Comment: Yeah, Mr. Wizard's answer works great for this