# Defining a symbolic inner product

Tags: symbolic, rule, attributes

So I have some rules for a symbolic inner product that work for quite a lot of cases:

```
SetAttributes[CircleDot, Orderless]
x_ \[CircleDot] 0 := 0
(x_ + a_)\[CircleDot] b_ := x \[CircleDot] b + a\[CircleDot] b
(x_ a_) \[CircleDot] b_  := x (a\[CircleDot] b) /; NumericQ[x]
```

This is great if all symbols are vectors, and the scalars satisfy `NumericQ == True`.

Does anyone know a good way to define symbolic scalars? I'd like some kind of 'MakeScalar' function which I can use to mark some of my symbols so that they're taken out of the inner product, and then all other symbols would be interpreted as vectors

I've tried messing around with setting `Attributes`, but they didn't work very well, partially because I need that if `a` is a scalar, so is `1/a`, `Sin[a]` etc. . Is it possible to assign `NumericQ` to be true for a given symbol? I'm not sure if this would be a good idea, but I think it would work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get a long way by directly declaring that the symbols in question are `NumericQ`.  For example, `θ` is normally treated as non-scalar:

```
CircleDot[a, Times[θ, b]]
(* CircleDot[a, Times[b, θ]] *)

CircleDot[a, Times[Sin[θ], b]]
(* CircleDot[a, Times[b, Sin[θ]]] *)
```

`NumericQ` is a protected symbol, but its built-in definition still permits direct assignment (in the same manner as other built-ins like `N` and `Format`).  Thus, as speculated in the question, we can define `θ` to be `NumericQ` to make it act like a scalar:

```
NumericQ[θ] = True;

CircleDot[a, Times[θ, b]]
(* Times[θ, CircleDot[a, b]] *)

CircleDot[a, Times[Sin[θ], b]]
(* Times[CircleDot[a, b], Sin[θ]] *)
```

We can take away the numeric status by executing `NumericQ[θ] =.`.

As noted in the question, we must take care when changing the meaning of symbols in this fashion.  It is probably not a good idea to change a common symbol like `i` since it `NumericQ` status affects many built-in functions.  Therefore, I suggest restricting such changes to letter forms that have no other function in your application, (e.g. Greek, double-struck, Gothic, Hebrew, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your help. `NumericQ[a] = True` works to remove `a` from the inner product, but eg. `Sin[a]` is not removed, and when I check, `NumericQ[Sin[a]]` evaluates to false, even though I have set `NumericQ` of `a` to be true. This seems strange to me, do you know why it is?

Comment: As you say, strange.  I just evaluated `NumericQ[a] = True; NumericQ[Sin[a]]` in every version of _Mathematica_ from V9 through V10.4.1 and got `True` every time.  What version are you using?  Is there any possibility of other definitions in your application that might interfere?

Comment: OK great thanks, I restarted the kernel and now it's fine with `a`, not sure what was going on there. Unluckily it's still not working for the case I want to use it in though. I am trying to use `Subscript[m,1]` as my variable, and I have called `Symbolize[Subscript[m,1]]`. After this I then call `NumericQ[Subscript[m,1]] = True` and then `NumericQ[Subscript[m,1]]` which evaluates to False, do you know anything about this?

Comment: The discussion in [(16976)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16976/142) is probably relevant.

Comment: Great thanks I'll take a look there

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your existing definitions:

```
(x_scalar a_)\[CircleDot]b_ := x (a\[CircleDot]b)
```

This specifies a definition similar to your last one that only applies when the `Head` of $x$ is `scalar`, an auxiliary operator we introduce.

Now, suppose that you want $t$ to be a scalar and $vec_i$ to be vectors:

```
(scalar[t] vec1) \[CircleDot] vec2   (* Out: vec1 \[CircleDot] vec2 scalar[t] *)
```

The auxiliary function `scalar` need not have any definition. It is just there as a wrapper to indicate the "type" of $t$.

If you don't want to see the `scalar` wrapper in your result, you can define a formatting rule for it:

```
Format[scalar[a_]] := a
```

The same expression above will then print as follows:

```
(scalar[t] vec1) \[CircleDot] vec2    (* Out: vec1 \[CircleDot] vec2 t *)
```

The scalar wrapper is retained, however:

```
InputForm[%]                          (* Out: vec1 \[CircleDot] vec2 * scalar[t] *)
```

Comment: To cover the case of `1/t`, `Sin[t]` as mentioned in the question, it could be useful to define an UpValue for `scalar` as follows: `scalar/:(f_/;MemberQ[Attributes[f],NumericFunction])[x_scalar,args___] := scalar[f[x,args]]`.

Comment: @MarcoB, do I understand correctly that with your method, every time I want eg. `m` to be a scalar, in my code I write `scalar[m]`?
@ Bruno, I have tried your code, and when executing `(1/scalar[m] a)\[CircleDot] b` ,  I get `During evaluation of In[117]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>`
`a\[CircleDot]b scalar[
  scalar[scalar[
    scalar[scalar[...` etc. Unluckily I don't understand it so I can't edit it myself